# Magento cannot use cli related to database

Tags: magento2

I use MAMP to run magento locally. Whenever I use cli related to the database. For example:

```
bin/magento store:list
bin/magento setup:db:status
```

I got this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client
```

Other commands work just fine, for example

```
 bin/magento cache:clean
```

This is my env file:

```
'db' => [
        'table_prefix' => '',
        'connection' => [
            'default' => [
                'host' => 'localhost',
                'dbname' => 'projectdev',
                'username' => 'test',
                'password' => '123456',
                'active' => '1',
                'driver_options' => [

                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
```

Note that I can install Magento successfully, so it apparently connects to my SQL. All the database credential is correct. However, it shows error when I use CLI.

I tried to change the host to `127.0.0.1` as well
PHP version: 7.3.9 SQL version: 5.7.26

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error while installing Magento2. I gave full access to the DB user but didn't fix the issue. Also, I don't know why I need to install Magento2 using CLI since I cloned the files from Github, which does not make any sense.